# J2me in Netbeans: How can I align my list items from right to left?

Tags: java, netbeans, sdk, java-me, right-to-left

I just created a simple java-me program for my cellphone with Netbeans 7.1
I have a splash screen and then a list with 4 items.
I want to align my list items from right to left `RTL`

Is there a way do do this?

Comment: have you used any gui like J2me Polish or LWUIT ?

Comment: @Lucifer No, I didn't use any GUI, How can I do this?

Comment: I dont understand : are the words like arabic language or is the problem just alignement problem ?

Comment: Dear @pheromix - The problem is the language, the program i'll write is a `Persian` program, Arabic and Persian are the same.

Comment: @pheromix - The problem is the language, the program i'll write is a Persian program, Arabic and Persian are the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the native midp widgets - you can't rely on having RTL support, since it's up to the device manufacturer to implement, if at all.
So you need to implement your UI on top of Canvas.

But there are widgets libraries that you can use to help you with that.
I personally recommend [LWUIT](http://lwuit.java.net/tutorial/index.html) for RTL work, since it was designed with RTL in mind - It was developed and still maintained in Israel, and many projects I know of with great RTL implementations use it.

And as a side bonus - your code will be easily portable to Android and ios (It's the library used by [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/)).

Comment: thanks alot, lwuit is good for this reason, but I prefer your first solution (implementing UI on top of Canvas)